# Square API + OAuth: How do I sign out of my iPad app?

Tags: ios, swift, oauth, square-connect

I am using Swift and the OAuthSwift pod to handle OAuth using an in app SFSafariViewController. Here's what it looks like for sign in:

[image]

The thing is, when I try to log out with this code:

```
  @IBAction func signOutButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let svc = SFSafariViewController(url: URL(string: "https://squareup.com/logout")!)
    self.present(svc, animated: true, completion: {
      print("signed outttt")
      appStore.dispatch(AppAction(type: .MerchantLogout()))
    })
  }
```

It opens the browser again and shows that page. The user is successfully logged out (the cookies are reset, etc) but I would like the browser to just close instead of showing the sign in form again. Signing in through that form does not call my OAuth callback. Instead it just signs them in and sends them to the square dashboard.

What's the proper way of signing out the user using an in app SFSafariViewController + OAuth?

Comment: Why do you want to sign out?

Comment: If there's a way to sign in there should be a way to sign out too

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I just ended up doing this:

```
  @IBAction func signOutButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let svc = SFSafariViewController(url: URL(string: "https://squareup.com/logout")!)

    self.present(svc, animated: true, completion: {
      appStore.dispatch(AppAction(type: .MerchantLogout()))
      self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    })
  }
```